# Returning an Array of Integers

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a method in which it will take an array of integers as a parameter, creates a new array that is the same size, copies the elements from the first array into the new array, and then returns a reference to the new array.

Right now, my code is as follows:

```
class CopyingAnArray {

  int[] cloneArray(int[] arr) {
    size = newarray.length;
    int[] newarray = new int[size];
    int[] copyarray = newarray;
    return copyarray;
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    ArrayTester converter = new ArrayTester();
    int[] newarray = {2,5,6,7};
    System.out.println(converter.cloneArray(newarray));
  }
}
```

Here is an explanation of what I think I am doing. I am taking the size of an array and putting it an array:

```
size = newarray.length;
int[] newarray = new int[size];
```

Then I am copying the array into a new array named `copyarray`. Then, I return `copyarray`.

```
int[] newarray = new int[size];
int[] copyarray = newarray;
return copyarray;
```

Any suggestions or advice on what I did wrong/solve the code?

so I tried doing this instead:
So, I will do something like this:

```
  int[] cloneArray(int[] arr) {
            int size=arr.length;
            int[] arr=new int[size];
            int[] arr=newarray;
            for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i]=newarray[i];
                return newarray[i];
   }
   }
```

I am still getting errors though.

Comment: ```Arrays.copyOf()``` does this for you.

Comment: How are you able to first use the variable `newarray` and then declare it later?

Comment: Check your scope on things. There isn't a ```newarray``` in ```cloneArray()```.

Comment: This is a big mess. You obviously haven't tried this, because it's far from compilable, and does nothing even if it were. You aren't  using your `arr` parameter in the function even once!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things. You need to declare size as an int. The major things: you never use the parameter passed to the method, arr. You use size = newarray.length when newarray doesn't exist yet. You try to make copyarray = new array, which doesn't make much sense. In addition, when setting two arrays equal to each other, you aren't really copying, you are only copying the reference to the array in memory. In order to copy, make a new array with the length of the parameter, then iterate over it with a for loop and copy each value into the new array, then return the new array. You can also always use Arrays.copyOf(array,array.length);